# how do i generate a yml file for my project with api and dto?

Tags: gradle, swagger, build.gradle

i have a problem with generating my yml. for some reason when i run the project it generate the yml but the dto or model are generated like this:

[generated yml from swagger annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJdRo.png)

this are my controller and dto. i was just testing but i don't know how to make it work properly.

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfBIW.png)

[Dto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHITA.png)

this is my build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "4.2.0"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "4.2.0"
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "5.3.0"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "core"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
    //OpenAPIDefinition
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
    compileOnly("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi-annotations")
    // Database
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbi")
    implementation("org.jdbi:jdbi3-core")
    implementation("org.jdbi:jdbi3-sqlobject")
    implementation("org.jdbi:jdbi3-vavr")
    runtimeOnly group: "com.microsoft.sqlserver", name: "mssql-jdbc", version: "9.4.0.jre17"

    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
    compileOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    runtimeOnly("org.yaml:snakeyaml")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("org.example.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}


graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("org.example.*")
    }
    aot {
        // Please review carefully the optimizations enabled below
        // Check https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aot/latest/guide/ for more details
        optimizeServiceLoading = false
        convertYamlToJava = false
        precomputeOperations = true
        cacheEnvironment = true
        optimizeClassLoading = true
        deduceEnvironment = true
        optimizeNetty = true
    }
}

ext {
    apiName = "prop-be-api"
    apiVersion = "1.0.6"
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("typescript-rxjs")
    inputSpec.set("$buildDir/classes/java/main/META-INF/swagger/core-0.0.yml".toString())
    outputDir.set("$buildDir/generated/npm/${apiName}-v${apiVersion}".toString())
    apiPackage.set("api")
    modelPackage.set("model")

    typeMappings = new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("DateTime", "string"); }}

    configOptions.set([
            "npmName": "@codegen/${apiName}",
            "npmVersion": "${apiVersion}"
    ])
}

tasks.named('openApiGenerate').configure {
    dependsOn compileJava
}

task openapiPackage(type: Tar) {
    from "$buildDir/generated/npm".toString()

    compression = Compression.GZIP

    archiveBaseName.set(apiName)
    archiveVersion.set(apiVersion)

    doLast {
        println archiveFileName.get()
        println relativePath(destinationDirectory)
        println relativePath(archiveFile)
    }
}

tasks.named('openapiPackage').configure {
    dependsOn 'openApiGenerate'
}

task copyApiToFe() {
    doLast {
        def fileName = "${apiName}-${apiVersion}.tgz"
        def source = "../prop-be/build/distributions/${fileName}"
        def target = "../prop-fe/api-packages"
        def packageJsonFile = "../prop-fe/package.json"
        def regexPattern = "\"@codegen/${apiName}\": \"file:api-packages/(.*?)\","
        def replaceString = "\"@codegen/${apiName}\": \"file:api-packages/${fileName}\","

        ant.move(file: source, todir: target)

        ant.replaceregexp(file: packageJsonFile, match: regexPattern, replace: replaceString, byline: true)
    }
}

task npmInstall() {
    doLast {
        exec {
            workingDir = file('../prop-fe')
            commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'npm', 'install'
        }
    }
}
```

i don't know how to solve my problem. maybe the problem is micronaut? i should be using maven?